# Accessing Websphere 6.1 variables

Tags: java, variables, websphere

I would like to get the value of the Websphere variable APP_INSTALL_ROOT from a java class. How can this be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this site:

http://www.slightlytallerthanaverageman.com/2007/04/02/access-websphere-variables-in-j2ee-applications/

Comment: I get the same variable surrounded by ${}. No security configured. Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

From IBM infocenter:

> You can use WebSphere variables to
>   provide settings for any of the string
>   data type attributes that are
>   contained in the product configuration
>   files.
>
> Because applications
>   cannot directly access WebSphere
>   variables, if you define a WebSphere
>   variable inside of an application, an
>   error message, such as "Unknown
>   variable," is returned. If you must
>   reference a WebSphere variable from
>   within an application, include the
>   following method in the application to
>   expand the string that uses the
>   WebSphere variable:

```
private String expandVariable(String s) throws
javax.management.JMException {  
com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminService as = 
com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminServiceFactory.getAdminService 
();  

String server = as.getProcessName();  

java.util.Set result = as.queryNames(new javax.management.ObjectName("*:*,type=AdminOperations,process=" 
+ server), null);  

return (String)as.invoke((javax.management.ObjectName) 
result.iterator().next(),"expandVariable",new Object[] 
{"${"+s+"}"}, new String[] {"java.lang.String"});
```

Comment: I get the same variable surrounded by ${}. No security configured. Any hints?

Comment: Should the string ""*:*,type=AdminOperations,process=" change in case the variable is in the cluster scope?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get the value of a Websphere variable in your app is to define a regular environment variable in the WAS console pointing to your Websphere variable:

1. Define your websphere variable someVariable = someValue
2. Go to (something like) Servers -> Server Types -> Websphere application
   servers -> YOUR_SERVER -> Java and process management -> Process
   definition -> Java virtual machine -> Custmo properties
3. Define a new variable someVariable = ${someVariable}

Now access the variable as System.getProperty("someVariable")

Comment: Parameters value load only at startup, therefore we have to restart WebSphere to update variable values.

Comment: Setting the value as part of the JVM works fine. However, it's better practice to use the WebSphere variables. "The variables scope across server, node, cluster, or cell".

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i can't write a comment.

> I get the same variable surrounded by ${}. No security configured. Any hints? – xain

You have to restart the server after your variables creation.