# Accessing Websphere variables

Tags: java, variables, websphere

I would like to get the value of the Websphere variable ORB_LISTENER_PORT from a java class. How it can be done?

I have read [topik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449981/accessing-websphere-6-1-variables) and understood it. I think i must use some value instead "expandVariable". But what kind of the value?

Comment: Note that in contrast to APP_INSTALL_ROOT (mentioned in the question you are linking to), ORB_LISTENER_PORT is not a WebSphere variable.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by yourself.
The following code sample and the result of his work.

```
import com.ibm.websphere.management.Session;
import com.ibm.websphere.management.configservice.ConfigService;
import com.ibm.websphere.management.configservice.ConfigServiceFactory;
import com.ibm.websphere.management.configservice.ConfigServiceHelper;

    public void readWebsphereConfiguration( PrintWriter out ){
        try{
            out.println("<p>Using ConfigService to get the hostName and port of this server.</p>");
            Session session = new Session();
            ConfigService cs = ConfigServiceFactory.getConfigService();

            ObjectName[] serverIndexONs = cs.resolve(session, "ServerIndex=");
            String hostName = (String) cs.getAttribute(session, serverIndexONs[0], "hostName");
            out.println("<p>HostName: " + hostName + "</p>");

            ObjectName[] namedEndPointsONs = cs.queryConfigObjects(session, serverIndexONs[0], ConfigServiceHelper.createObjectName(null, "NamedEndPoint"), null);
            for (int i = 0; i < namedEndPointsONs.length; ++i){
                String str = (String) cs.getAttribute(session, namedEndPointsONs[i], "endPointName");
                ObjectName[] theEndPoints = cs.queryConfigObjects(session, namedEndPointsONs[i], ConfigServiceHelper.createObjectName(null, "EndPoint"), null);
                String szValue = "";
                if(theEndPoints != null && theEndPoints.length > 0){
                    szValue = ((Integer) cs.getAttribute(session, theEndPoints[0], "port")).toString();
                }
                out.println("<p>" + str + "=" + szValue +"</p>");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            out.println("<p>Exception while trying to fetch the hostname and port information.: " + e.getMessage() + "</p>");
            out.println("<p>Exception:" + e.getStackTrace() + "</p>");
        }
    }
```

Listing of function is:

- BOOTSTRAP_ADDRESS=2809
- SOAP_CONNECTOR_ADDRESS=8880
- SAS_SSL_SERVERAUTH_LISTENER_ADDRESS=9401
- CSIV2_SSL_SERVERAUTH_LISTENER_ADDRESS=9403
- CSIV2_SSL_MUTUALAUTH_LISTENER_ADDRESS=9402
- WC_adminhost=9060
- WC_defaulthost=9080
- DCS_UNICAST_ADDRESS=9353
- WC_adminhost_secure=9043
- WC_defaulthost_secure=9443
- ORB_LISTENER_ADDRESS=9100
- SIP_DEFAULTHOST=5060
- SIP_DEFAULTHOST_SECURE=5061
- SIB_ENDPOINT_ADDRESS=7276
- SIB_ENDPOINT_SECURE_ADDRESS=7286
- SIB_MQ_ENDPOINT_ADDRESS=5558
- SIB_MQ_ENDPOINT_SECURE_ADDRESS=5578
- IPC_CONNECTOR_ADDRESS=9633
- OVERLAY_UDP_LISTENER_ADDRESS=11003
- OVERLAY_TCP_LISTENER_ADDRESS=11004